# Problem with cartopy when a shapefile as lon > 180

Tags: shapefile, latitude-longitude, shapely, cartopy

I am trying to make a figure using a shapefile and cartopy.

- When longitudes are in the range [-180,180] everything is working fine
- When longitudes are in the range [0, 360]   the shapefile is not showing

Note that if I am looking the shapefile with other tools, the shapefile are showing correctly (for both cases)

Here is a simplified example (with a square shapefile) that reproduce my problem

```
import cartopy.crs            as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as cshpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot      as plt
import shapefile

polygon = {}
d = 0
polygon[0] = [[-100+d,40], [-100+d,50], [-90+d,50], [-90+d,40], [-100+d,40]]
d = 360
polygon[1] = [[-100+d,40], [-100+d,50], [-90+d,50], [-90+d,40], [-100+d,40]]

for i in range(2):
   # Shapefile creation
   shp_file = './file_' + str(i) + '.shp'
   shp = shapefile.Writer(shp_file, shapefile.POLYGON)
   shp.field('name', 'C')
   shp.poly([polygon[i]])
   shp.record('watershape')
   shp.close()

   # Shapefile reading
   shapel = list(cshpreader.Reader(shp_file).geometries())

   # Figure
   plt.figure(i)
   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   #ax.set_extent([xll, xur, yll, yur], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   ax.add_geometries(shapel, ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='r', facecolor='b', linewidths=2, alpha=0.5)
   plt.title('Figure '   + str(i) )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the explanation provided by @swatchai, here is the solution to my problem:

```
# Shapefile reading
shapel = list(cshpreader.Reader(shp_file).geometries())
sf = shapefile.Reader(shp_file)
xll, yll, xur, yur = sf.bbox
if   xll >  180: shapel = [shapely.affinity.translate(shapel[0],-360, 0)]
elif xur < -180: shapel = [shapely.affinity.translate(shapel[0], 360, 0)]
```

**Explanation**: In my example the valid region of a CRS is lon in [-180,180].
To fix it, we only have to shift longitude by +/- 360 when all vertices are outside this rang.

**Case 1: xll > 180**
The x-value of lower left corner (xll) of the bouding box is larger than 180.
This mean all longitude are larger than 180.
To sanitize the coordinates, we have to shift the longitude by -360.

**Case 2: xur < -180**
The x-value of upper right corner (xur) of the bouding box is smaller than -180.
This mean all longitude are smaller than -180.
To sanitize the coordinates, we have to shift the longitude by +360.

A more general solution for the case where:

```
  xll >  180 + n*360 
  xur < -180 - n*360
```

is straightforward to implement.

Maybe it would be simpler to simply change the valid region of a CRS, but (if its is possible) I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Cartopy has its own rules to plot or not to plot geometries.
In your case, when `d = 360`, the polygon[1] will be created as:

```
POLYGON ((260 40, 260 50, 270 50, 270 40, 260 40)).
```

and it is not plotted. This signifies that you need to sanitize your coordinates for all geometry objects. If all the vertices of a certain geometry fall outside the valid region of a CRS or specified plot extent, it can't be plotted.

And if `d = 275`,

```
POLYGON ((175 40, 175 50, 185 50, 185 40, 175 40))
```

The polygon is split into 2 parts by the dateline and its geometry is plotted nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically, if no longitude are located inside the range [0,180], cartopy will not show any figure. I must fix the longitude issue before to pass the shapefile to cartopy?

Comment: @VincentPoitras I think so.